# error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it. java.lang.String tocd);

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I was developing sme regular room app where I  try to keep same data into a localdatabase using room. I'm getting the following error:

```
error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    java.lang.String tocd);
                     ^
```

Regarding my LocaDatabase class is this:

```
@Database(entities = [SessionData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)
abstract class LocalDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dao(): CepsaDAO

}
```

My data class model:

```
@Entity(tableName = Constants.DB_NAME)
data class SessionData (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) val tcod: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sessionToken") val sessionToken: String,
)
```

And my DAO:

```
@Dao
interface CepsaDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertTocd(tocd: String):Long   //This method rise the error 

    @Query("SELECT tcod FROM ${Constants.DB_NAME}")
    fun getTocd():String?

    @Query("SELECT sessionToken FROM ${Constants.DB_NAME} WHERE tcod=:tocd")
    fun getSessionData(tocd:String): String?

    @Query("DELETE FROM ${Constants.DB_NAME} WHERE sessionToken=:token")
    fun deleteSessionId(token: String):Int
}
```

And in order to instanciate i'm using dagger plugin:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class LocalModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDB(@ApplicationContext context: Context): LocalDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            context.applicationContext,
            LocalDatabase::class.java,
            Constants.DB_NAME
        ).build()
    }
}

@ActivityRetainedScoped
class LocalDatabaseUseCase @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var db : LocalDatabase

... Some code
}
```

So I see some solution in stackoverflow and github forums, like downground the kotlin version or the upgrade the room version, but doesn't work.

Here is my build.gralde(app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

dependencies{

kotlin_version=1.8.10
kotlin_serialization=1.5.0
core_ktx_version=1.10.1
room_version=2.5.0

implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$kotlin_serialization"

//Room libraries
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```

So, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertTocd(tocd: String):Long   //This method rise the error
```

The `insertTocd` function is trying/saying to insert into the table that is defined via the **String** class. The kotlin **String** class does not have the `@Entity` annotation. Obviously it never would or could. It is part of Kotlin.

When you insert into the database you insert data into the column(s) of a table table. Room determines the table(s) via the classes specified in the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotation. The columns for a table are ascertained according to the fields of the `@Entity` annotated class(es).

You have a single class so defined according to `@Database(entities = [SessionData::class], version = 1, exportSchema = true)` as such you can only  insert data into the `Constants.DB_NAME` table. When using the convenience `@Insert` then the object type passed to the function must be an `@Entity` annotated class that is defined via the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation.

It would appear that you are trying to insert a row into the table just using the **tcod** value.

What you could do is use an `@Query` to do the insert e.g.

```
@Query("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ${Constants.DB_NAME} VALUES(:tcod,'whatever would be a suitable default value');")
fun insertTocd(tcod: String)
```

- **note** this would not return a value

Alternately and perhaps more likely what you want, you could use something like:-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(sessionData: SessionData): Long

fun insertTocd(tcod: String): Long {
    return insert(SessionData(tcod,"whatever would be a suitable default value")
}
```

- note this would return a value, it would be the **rowid** of the inserted row. **rowid** is a special column, that always exists for tables (when using Room). If the row could not be inserted then the value would be -1.
- both cases `whatever would be a suitable default value` could be any value but not null as the type String will have a NOT NULL constraint applied.

Comment: Thanks for such completed answer. It's works !